# Using twilio flex, what is the recommended way of creating different environments? DEV, PROD etc

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I realize I could literally spin up a whole different twilio flex project,and have a project constitute the separation. 
But is there a better way of accomplishing this that is recommended?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Right now the best way is to set up a new project for a different environment.